# Even sign configurations with prescribed support

Tags: co.combinatorics

$\def\p{\phantom-}$Call a $\lbrace 0,-1,1\rbrace$-matrix $M$ an even sign configuration if every row of $M$ contains an even number of 1's and every column of $M$ contains an even number of $-1$'s. The matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} \p1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\\\ -1 & \p1 & 0 & 1 \\\\ \p0 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\\\ -1 &  \p0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
is an example of an even sign configuration. The support of such a matrix $M$ is the matrix obtained from $M$ by taking absolute values.

Given a $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$-matrix $A$ of square size $d\times d$, is it possible to decide in polynomial time (with respect to $d$) if $A$ is the support of an even sign configuration?

More or less equivalently, if a $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$-matrix $A$ is the support of an even sign configuration, does there exist a polynomial time algorithm which finds an even sign configuration $M$ with support $A$?

This question is essentially question  [Complexity of a matching problem on the grid $\mathbb Z^2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116592/complexity-of-a-matching-problem-on-the-grid-mathbb-z2) with the no-intersection condition removed.

Algebraic reformulation: An even sign configuration $M$ corresponds to two 
$\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$ matrices $A_+,A_-$ such that $M=A_+ -A_-$ such that 
$A_+ (A_-)^t$ has only zeros on the diagonal and the support of $M$ is given by $A_+ +A_-$.

Added after Domotorp's comment: It seems that finding a perfect matching in an arbitrary graph is NP-complete (Added afterwards: WRONG, see Tony Huynh's answer). (This would solve the problem: Consider the graph with vertices corresponding to all non-zero entries, put an edge between two vertices if they are either on a common row or column. Find a complete matching in this graph if it exists.
Put a $-1$ at every vertex matched to a vertex of the same column and a $+1$ otherwise.)
The graph associated as above is however special. The question makes thus still sense
and is essentially a question on the existence of an efficient algorithm finding a complete
matching in the class of graphs defined by supports of matrices (or equivalently by finite
subsets of $\mathbb Z^2$).

Comment: I don't get it - if A has a row or column with an odd number of 1's, it cannot have an even sign configuration, while if this is not the case, you can pick M=A.

Comment: I also don't see why this question is similar to the grid-matching problem, but if you remove the intersection condition there, then it is just about finding a matching in a graph (with max degree 4), so it is in P.

Comment: @domotorp: Your first comment refers to a bugged version containing the wrong definition, I have corrected it since. I do not know if this answers your second question. But if finding a matching in an arbitrary graph is in P the answer to my question is YES (you cannot suppose that the degree is $4$ however).

Comment: Why would you write that after my comment it seems that finding a matching is NP-complete when I wrote that it is in P? Whatever...

Comment: @domotorp: I think it was an honest mistake by Roland, since he must have assumed that you meant that finding a perfect matching is only in P for graphs of maximum degree 4.  Indeed, the main point of my answer was just to clear up this confusion.  

Comment: @domotorp: I got effectively a little bit confused about complexity-issues for perfect matchings: part of the confusion arose out of the similar notions of maximal matching (a matching which cannot
be extended to a larger matching) and maximum matching (involving 
the largest possible number of edges). I first believed that only finding a maximal matching is in P (which is of course easy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both of your questions is **yes**.

As suggested by the edit, consider the graph  $G(A)$ whose vertex set is the set of non-zero entries of $A$, and where two entries are adjacent if they are in the same row or column.  Now, as mentioned in the latest edit, if $G(A)$ contains a perfect matching then $A$ is the support of an even sign configuration.  On the other hand, if $A$ is the support of an even sign configuration, then it is easy to construct a perfect matching in $G(A)$.

Thus $A$ is the support of an even sign configuration if and only if $G(A)$ has a perfect matching.

Now, by [Edmond's Blossom Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27s_matching_algorithm), the problem of finding a perfect matching in an arbitrary graph (not just maximum degree 4) is in P.  So both of your problems can be solved in polynomial-time.

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks like a great algorithm that would perhaps 
deserve to be better known!

Comment: You're welcome.  It is indeed a beautiful algorithm of my great-grandfather.  